Unable to Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database
When deploying our on premises database to Azure SQL Database with SSMS, using the feature 'Deploy Databse to Microsoft Azure SQL Database' we get the following error:
One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error SQL71627: The element User: [xxx\SSO UAT Administrators] has property AuthenticationType set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
Error SQL71627: The element Login: [xxx\SSO UAT Administrators] has property IsMappedToWindowsLogin set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
 (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Can someone let me know if there is anyway to get around this issue?

Please forget about SSMS for migrating databases to Azure SQL Database. Use Microsoft Data Migration Assistant (DMA) for this task. This tool is the easiest way to migrate to Azure SQL Database. It performs an assessment first, then it migrates your databases to Azure.
If DMA finds any incompatibilities resolve them and use DMA for migration. Please follow this tutorial.

The element User: [xxx\SSO UAT Administrators] has property AuthenticationType set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12. 
Error SQL71627: The element Login: [xxx\SSO UAT Administrators] has property IsMappedToWindowsLogin set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

Azure SQL database doesn't support Windows authentication. It supports only SQL Server authentication and Microsoft Enterprise ID authentication. However, the above user is mapped to Windows authentication, which may be the reason for the error. If you want to deploy the on-premises SQL database to Azure SQL Database, delete the user mapped to Windows authentication as shown below:

Then try deploying again. After deployment, create contained users in your database to allow users to log in to your SQL Database.
Alternatively, you can use Azure Data Migration Assistant (DMA) for your migration project, which will make the process much easier. DMA assesses your database and allows you to migrate effortlessly. You can download the tool from here. With DMA, you can uncheck any logins (SQL71627) or views not compatible with Azure SQL (SQL71561) and proceed with the migration.
For more information, you can refer to the links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/689900/error-while-migrating-on-prem-sql-db-to-azure-sql
Can't Export Data-tier Application for Azure

